# Issue while building zeppelin ERROR: spawn npm ENOENT

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I am using the following command to build zeppelin 0.8 on ubuntu

> mvn clean package -Pbuild-distr -Pyarn -Pspark-1.6
>   -Dspark.version=1.6.0 -Phadoop-2.6 -Dhadoop.version=2.6.0-cdh5.9.0 -DskipTests -Pvendor-repo

I am getting following error

```
[WARNING] warning Unmet peer dependency "eslint@>=3.8.1".
[INFO] [4/4] Building fresh packages...
[INFO] $ bower install --silent
[INFO] Done in 77.54s.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.3:yarn (yarn build) @ zeppelin-web ---
[INFO] Running 'yarn run build' in /home/[USER]/zeppelin/zeppelin-web
[INFO] yarn run v0.18.1
[INFO] $ npm-run-all clean
[ERROR] ERROR: spawn npm ENOENT
[ERROR] error Command failed with exit code 1.
[INFO] info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
.

[INFO] Zeppelin: web Application ......................... FAILURE [1:20.415s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Server .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Zeppelin: Packaging distribution .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4:35.974s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Jan 27 08:44:39 PST 2017
[INFO] Final Memory: 196M/464M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.3:yarn (yarn build) on project zeppelin-web: Failed to run task: 'yarn run build' failed. (error code 1) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

Answer (score 2):

Installing npm on the host resolved the issue for me